# Using SpringBatch and StaxEventItemWriter to generate xml file, how to write attribute for element?

Tags: xml, spring-batch

I have used `SpringBatch` and `StaxEventItemWriter` to generate `XML` file for records read from a database table. I know, how to add attribute to the root element, but I do not know, how to do it for other elements.

E.g., how to add the "converted" attribute for the `MarketValue` tag?

```
<MarketValue converted="true" >5140150.70351</MarketValue>
```

Details:

This is what I am trying to do: read from db, and populate class `AssetInflowReport` (simplified):

```
public class AssetInflowReport
{
    private String Currency;
    private Double MarketValue;
}
```

In `Springbatch`, use the writer, `Fbo_assetInflowReport_Writer_xml`, in the below step to generate the xml output file:

```
<batch:step id="FBO_extract_assetInflowReport" >
   <batch:chunk reader="assetInflowReportItemReader" writer="Fbo_assetInflowReport_Writer_xml" commit-interval="10000" />
```

`Fbo_assetInflowReport_Writer_xml` is defined like this:

```
<bean id="Fbo_assetInflowReport_Writer_xml" 
class="com.rbccm.lrma.batch.writer.IndentingStaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:${fbo.output.dir}/Fbo_assetInflowReport-${businessDate}.xml" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="assetInflowReportMarshaller" />
</bean>
<bean id="assetInflowReportMarshaller" 
class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
    <property name="aliases">
        <util:map id="aliases">
            <entry key="assetInflowReport" value="com.rbccm.lrma.batch.model.AssetInflowReport" />
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Class `IndentingStaxEventItemWriter extends org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter`, it generate xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assetInflowReport treasuryControl="true" reportID="1">
<assetInflowReport treasuryControl="true" reportID="1"> 
    <assetInflowReport>
      <Currency>USD</Currency>
      <MarketValue>5140150.70351</MarketValue>
    </assetInflowReport>
```

The problem is, we need to add an attribute, "converted",  to `<MarketValue>` tag, e.g., make it look like:

```
<MarketValue converted="true" >5140150.70351</MarketValue>
```

checked `StaxEventItemWriter` and `XStreamMarshaller`; I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: That really depends on your XML Serializer.  It's the configuration of that which determines how the XML looks on the way out.  If you share your configuration, we may be able to help.

Comment: thx Michael, I've updated the question with details :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, try to represent your problem briefly and leave unnecessary points which are not directly related to your problem, so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!